# How to disconnect from a server in Kiwi IRC

Tags: irc, kiwi-irc

[Kiwi IRC](https://kiwiirc.com) is a webapp for IRC.

I thought it was quite popular as it's been around for a couple of years and feels very slick and professional but there don't seem to be any previous questions about it here.

I know there is a standard IRC command `/server` to connect to a new/extra server.

But what about when you've finished with one server and want to close it but keep any others you are using going? I couldn't find anything in Kiwi's docs or by googling to see how to disconnect from a server once I'm done with it.

Comment: Does the plain /quit disconnect the entire web app?

Comment: @panhandel: Aha `/quit` seems to disconnect only from the current server, but doesn't close its tab/icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kiwi IRC dev here—the network tabs not closing when you issue a `/quit` is a known bug right now and should be fixed soon.

It will most likely in the next release in the upcoming week, which includes closing networks via the UI also.

Comment: Mm... Not fixed yet in 2015 :/